# Efficient and non-error-prone way to represent a struct buffer?

Tags: c, memory-management, buffer, binary-data

Let's say I wish to conform to a memory model laid out in the following structure (as binary data in some file):

```
typedef struct fileSection_s {

    unsigned int a[ 3 ];

    unsigned int b[ 3 ]; 

} fileSection_t;
```

There is an arbitrary amount of `fileSection_t` structs, and using C, I'd like to know of an efficient and non-error-prone means of:

- Allocating an arbitrary amount of `fileSection_t` structs as a buffer, without resorting to something error-prone(?) such as: 
  `fileSection_t** buf = (fileSection_t**) malloc( sizeof( fileSection_t* ) * count)`;
   (i.e., avoiding use of double pointers where possible)
- Using memcpy to take a `uint8_t*` pre-computed segment of binary data read from the file into said buffer, which is meant to hold `n` amount of `fileSection_t` struct instances.
- Accessing said `fileSection_t` instances later on (on a one-by-one basis), not as some generic buffer type (e.g., `void*` or `uint8_t*`) but as `fileSection_t*` (pointer arithmetic/conversion maybe?).

Explanations of common methodologies or well-known "best-practices" would be appreciated as well.

My main goal is to essentially define some kind of common C-like interface which will allow me to allocate some arbitrary buffer-like object and store whatever kind of struct memory I wish inside of it, without losing the flexibility of iteration and what not...and also having a similar effect of what is gained via using a `pointer-to-pointer` mechanism, albeit without that second pointer.

For example,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct fileSection_s {

    unsigned int a[ 3 ];

    unsigned int b[ 3 ]; 

} fileSection_t;

typedef struct buffer_s {

    size_t       elementSize;

    unsigned int currentLength;

    unsigned int maxLength;

    void*        mem; // or uint8_t*? 

} buffer_t;

int main( void ) {

    buffer_t* a = ( buffer_t* ) malloc( sizeof( buffer_t ) );
    a->mem = malloc( sizeof( fileSection_t ) * count );
    a->maxLength = count;
    a->currentLength = 0;
    a->elementSize = sizeof( fileSection_t );

    FILE* f = fopen( "some_binary_data", "rb");

    ...

    uint8_t* fileMemory = ( uint8_t* )malloc( size( uint8_t ) * fileSize ); // assume fileSize is obtained via ftell


    fread( fileMemory, fileSize, sizeof( uint8_t ) );

    ...
    ...


    // someOffset is obtained earlier
    memcpy( a->mem, fileMemory + someOffset, sizeof( fileSection_t ) ); 

    ...

    // now somehwere, we need to grab a section of our buffer and cast to fileSection_t. 


    return 0;
}
```

So, what I'd like to be able to do is get a section of the buffer and cast to a **pointer to fileSection_t** in a **safe** manner. The functionality is exactly like an array, but the means of obtaining said functionality (at least, AFAIK) in this case involve using pointer arithmetic and byte casting instead.

Comment: Why would you use double pointers for allocating a bunch of `fileSection_t`s? `fileSection_t * buf = malloc(sizeof(fileSection_t) * count);` should work just fine, and doesn't require you to `malloc` all the individual `fileSection_t`s as well.

Comment: That's why I'm asking this question in the first place: to understand the semantics, advantages, and disadvantages for these methods. The point is not **why do this?**, the point is **what can I do as an alternative, and WHY is it better?** If you down voted me for not explaining this clearly enough, do tell so I can at least correct that in the actual post.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this answers your question but on StackOverflow, it seems the accepted practice for using malloc is

```
type *ptr = malloc(sizeof(*p))
```

and

```
type *array = malloc(sizeof(*array) * n)
```

No types in the sizeof() and no cast. This is the least error prone way to use malloc.

Comment: I added some more detail towards the bottom; I hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: If you are reading the entire file at once, why not just read directly into a->mem and then index that when you want to extract the sections?